# Preparedquery vulnerable to Sql injection

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, c#-4.0, webforms, owasp

I am running OWASP Zap as a security review for our code.

A SQL injection is being detected when we are using preparedquery and I am struggling to determine why? The basis of our code is:

```
DLPreparedQuery preparedQuery = this._env.Conn.Prepare("select a from Table1",
                    new DLDataTypes[] { DLDataTypes.BigInt, DLDataTypes.Char, DLDataTypes.BigInt, DLDataTypes.BigInt, DLDataTypes.Char, DLDataTypes.BigInt },
                    new string[] { "@P1", "@P2", "@P3", "@P4", "@P5", "@P6" },
                    DLQueryOptions.Default, -1);

object[,] objResult = (object[,])preparedQuery.Query(1, 'ABC', 'DEF', 1,'AAA',21);
```

We also escape all user input text with antixss using

Microsoft.Security.Application.Encoder.HtmlEncode(inputData)

Are there settings I should be looking at at SQLServer?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The escape you do with antixss is totally wrong ! The HtmlEncode is (must) used only when you render text on your web page - have nothing to do with sql injection and the data you going to save on sql.

Answer (score 0):

Haven’t worked with preparedquery but I’d suggest you run sql profiler until you identify the malicious statement. After identifying how statement looks like, you’ll most probably know what to do.

HtmlEncode doesn’t work here. I’d suggest you try replacing single quote ‘ with two single quotes. This is not a bullet proof solution but it’s likely to give you good results.

If your database is in full recovery mode you can try using some third party transaction log reader to scan through already executed statements and try to identify what could be the issue.